# Multiline string bottom trim

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
This is a test.


\\

{panel}


This is a second test.


\\

{panel}
```

I would like to remove all the new lines and the `\\` between the last string and the `{panel}` block.

Is there a regex that can help me?

Comment: You don't need a `regex` for this. Two simple global string replacements are enough.

Comment: The number of lines or the number of `\\\` is variable

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: @revo Yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460843/736291 and it seems working. I had to do some trial and errors.

Comment: What language are you working with? Are there any cases that you don't want to match?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try replacing this:

```
(\r\n)*\\\\(\r\n)*
```

meaning: any number of newlines followed by a \ followed by a newline one or more times

With:

```
\r\n
```

meaning: a newline

Answer (score 0):

I tried this regex and it seems working properly:

`^[\n\\]+{panel}`

with `igm` as modifiers.

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/6